# Drupal 7 Views 3: Displaying the number of displayed nodes? Example: (Showing 3842 of 5382 results)

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-modules

How could we display the number of displayed nodes in a View? Like:
"Showing 3842 of 5382 results"

Then if all nodes in the View are displayed at once, (often initially), it might say:
"Showing all 5382 results"

Then if no nodes in the View are displayed from the filter, it might say:
"Found no results"

Is this very hard? I think it would be a very useful addition and would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this could be done more succinctly. But I wanted to make it clear what I was doing. So here it is. Basically you can use this in the header or footer of your view.

```
<?php
$view = views_get_current_view();
$c = $view->total_rows;
$cp = $view->get_current_page();
$pp = $view->get_items_per_page();
$si = ($cp * $pp) + 1;
$ei = $si + ($pp - 1);

if($c > 0) {
  if($pp < $c) {
    if($ei > $c) {
      print "Showing $si to $c of $c results";
    } else {
      print "Showing $si to $ei of $c results";
    }
  } else {
    print "Showing all $c results";
  }
} else {
  print "Found no results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) go to edit view

2) add field

3) Global: View result counter

4) Profit.

Comment: Didn't know this existed. Assuming you don't need any custom formatting, I would go with this solution over mine below.

Comment: That's can be formatted as well, either via custom output or field template.

Comment: This does not do what what the question asks for (adding a counter to the search result), instead this adds a counter for each search result in the table (the counter for the first result is '1', for second '2'). In order to determine how many matches there were you'd have to go to the last page of the search result.